# Planning web applications

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm about to start building new start-up so i need some guidelines from you.

What's the best way to plan a website? I don't think like "first design, then the database relations, then start development", but "how to plan the way application is going to work"?

Are there some proven methods, like THE best way to do website 'blueprints', like with some tool or something?

I need as much feedback as you people can give me, this is really important to me.

Links, experiences, everything is welcome =)

I'd like some tool to be able to draw the process like

page
    - if logged in - do that
    - if not logged in - do that 2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Write it down. On a piece of paper. Draw lines between the related parts.

Rinse and repeat as necessarily.

I'm serious. Tools, fancy diagrams, flowcharts, all look pretty for management, but they get in the way of actually understanding how your app is going to work. If it's so complex you can't get it all on a couple sheets of paper, do a big picture view and then do each sub-section.

If you can get a *HUGE* whiteboard or piece of butcher paper, it's even better. For some reason, having a large space to work on is fantastic for working things out.

Comment: I know others have mentioned using tools, but honestly I've had the absolute best success with a note book and a couple of colored pens/pencils.  You can easily carry it around, whip it out, and rearrange ideas to your hearts content.

Answer (score 4):

I used to do huge specifications in word...hundred pages or more.  I no longer believe in that since as soon as you write it down it is likely to change (your ideas, features, etc.).  Instead I suggest that you look at an MS product called SketchFlow (which comes with Blend).  This allows you to quickly and without writing any code snap together a working wireframe, sitemap, and mock up.  While you can create a high fidelity (it functions and looks very close to the real thing) I suggest that you instead focus on creating a low fidelity mock up.  There are sketch styles which looks like hand drawn UI elements.  This way you can focus purely on how your product works and no so much about how it looks.  If there is too much 'finish' put on your mock up you will get hung up on the "big blue button" syndrome where people are more concerned with how a button looks and less concerned with what it does.

I wrote four articles on wireframes, mock ups, and the like and suggest various tools and why I chose SketchFlow.  Then I go into building a mock up in SketchFlow.

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Building-a-StackOverflow-inspired-Knowledge-Exchange-Sitemap-and-wireframes-with-Expression-Blend-3-and-SketchFlow-part-1.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Building-a-StackOverflow-inspired-Knowledge-Exchange-Sitemap-and-wireframes-with-Expression-Blend-3-and-SketchFlow-part-2.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Building-a-StackOverflow-inspired-Knowledge-Exchange-Sitemap-and-wireframes-with-Expression-Blend-3-and-SketchFlow-part-3.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Building-a-StackOverflow-inspired-Knowledge-Exchange-Sitemap-and-wireframes-with-Expression-Blend-3-and-SketchFlow-part-4.aspx

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Also, if you are doing starts up you should subscribe to the podcast "this week in startups".  Lots of great free information.  They talk about concepts such as Free, ABC (not always be closing but always be cheap!), etc.  It will all apply to your issues!  http://thisweekinstartups.com/

Comment: Also Balsamiq Mockups is similar to SketchFlow but has that cross platform feel.

Comment: +1 for "as soon as you write it down it is likely to change."

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty big question. My best advice is to start by thinking hard about your user, what their goals are etc and then draw up some personas. Personas are descriptions of the typical people who will use your site. Once you have your personas you can start to plan your site.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personas

Once you have your personas you can work out user journeys - these are essentially flow diagrams detailing how users will achieve the tasks you want to help them with.

http://www.boxesandarrows.com/view/an_introduction_to_user_journeys

From user journeys you can work out the pages you'll need to create in the form of a site map.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map

Then finally you can work out the content of the pages as wireframes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website_wireframe

There are loads of tools out there: Visio (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/FX100487861033.aspx) for the PC and Omnigraffle (http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/) for the Mac. Both these tools have web design stencils available for free download on the web. There's also a great online tool call Balsamiq (http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) that allows you to lay out pages without having to use a design tool. In the first instance though a pen and paper are the only tools you need.

Once you have these details sorted you can start to think about data models, graphic design etc etc. However this whole process is iterative and you might say will never be finished :)

Good luck!

Comment: +1 @andrewdotcom. Very helpful info, especially the introduction to user journeys. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Develop your data model first.  Even if you don't go whole-hog with UML, get a sense of how your data will be represented.

Come up with some use cases to validate your data model.  It doesn't have to be perfect, but it should be 99% there to avoid pain in the future.

Once you have a data model and use cases, your interface needs (in your case, your website) will become a great deal clearer.  Of course, I'm coming at this from a purely back-end perspective.

Once you have an interface that's workable, hire a good UX specialist to round out the details for you (both workflow and actual interface).

Comment: Sorry, but the data model should be pretty close to the last thing you look at.  The first thing is figuring out the problem you want to solve.  Those problems are going to drive site layout and, eventually, the data model will become apparent.