# Web Project planning tutorial

Tags: web-applications, project-management, project-planning

I am about to start a web project in PHP/MySql and would like to do proper planning but i have no experience in doing this, so i am looking for an online tutorial i can read that will help me learn how to plan web projects.

Please post resourcesful links.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

1. Read [What should a developer know before building a public web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site)
2. Define and document scope
3. Define and document functional requirements
4. Look for existing solutions - if you can leverage a CMS or eCommerce package you can save a lot of development time
5. Design database (ER Diagram)
6. Design website structure (sections, links, navigation)
7. Design page layout - wireframe tools or even paper/pencil are useful for this
8. Design application structure - high level class structure
9. Identify libraries and frameworks, e.g., Doctrine, Zend, CodeIgnitor, etc
10. Technical design decisions - naming conventions, logging strategy, exception handling
11. Testing Plan
12. Implementation Plan

**Sources**

- [PHP project planning for idiots](http://www.ericbieller.com/post/56719641064/php-project-planning-for-idiots-mvc-design-pattern)
- PHP Application Development ([part 1](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/PHP-Application-Development-Part-One/) and [part 2](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/PHP-Application-Development-Part-Two/))
- [Web Application Development - A Guide to Success](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/development-guide-success)
- StackOverflow

  - [How to plan my web based project before starting code ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983916/how-to-plan-my-web-based-project-before-starting-code)
  - [Web Design Process - Planning Stage…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215976/web-design-process-planning-stage)
  - [How to design/plan for web application development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752770/how-to-design-plan-for-web-application-development)
  - [Planning web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639820/planning-web-applications)
  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[web-development]+plan